# Rename tag after it's been submitted

Tags: discussion

I've just created the tag [sublime-snippets], but realised that the other tags relating to Sublime Text call it `sublimetext`, so a better name for the tag would have probably been `sublimetext-snippets`.

1. Do you agree?

<strike>Is it possible for me to change this?</strike>

*The answer to this bit is no.*

Comment: Certainly gratuitious inconsistency is anathema to programmers.